# How to remove unknown property created during opening of a mat-select modal

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I am facing problem on removing unknown division created during opening of a mat-select.

When I am opening a modal and after selecting values ,I need to click directly on the button given on side but because of some property of modal a div is getting created and I have to do **two** clicks on the button to apply changes.

Right now when I am clicking outside the **mat-select** modal to make it close then clicking on button it is going correct. But I need to open modal -> select options -> direct click on the button given.

Something in the background is blocking the first click when opening a **mat-select**  modal. I am not able to see what is that. Is there some css property that can be block ? I am not getting exact hidden problem.

Answer (score 1):

Modals in Angular Material create something that's called 'backdrop' by default. This backdrop is like a layer right behind your modal, filling the whole page. If you click somewhere on the page, your target will be the backdrop, which then closes the modal.

So for you to achieve, what you want to achieve, you have the following options:

- edit the backdrop behavior to not prevent the default click action, so that clicks on the backdrop close the modal but also trigger the action you want
- remove the backdrop on opening of the modal (this can be done by setting a flag `hasBackdrop` in the `open` methods config parameters) and close the modal programmatically by triggering the `close` method of the MatDialogRef

Comment: I am using mat-select now. How can I do the same with that. Added [disableRipple] : true at `<mat-select>` then also not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard modal behavior, you should include all your needed options either before opening a modal or in the modal itself after being opened.

Comment: Didn't get this statement "you should include all your needed options either before opening a modal or in the modal itself after being opened" . Isn't there any work around or angular mat modal properties to disable , so that I can directly do single click on other component ?

Comment: The question itself, is it logical to modify the modal contents from outside it while it's opened? I believe not.
That's why I'm telling you as a modal behavior applied and displays a shadow, one thing is meant is to only focus on the modal content, maybe the user ca a 
checkbox or even enter a text value and then confirm, but from outside it !!